# Get Timepicker Value C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, timepicker

I have a timepicker control from Xceed WPF toolkit. 
1. How i can get user selected time input value from it and put it in a textbox? 
2. How i can add some integer value stored in a variable and add them as minutes to the timepicker time?
Thanks

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           mytimepicker = new TimePicker();
          if (mytimepicker.Value != null)
          {
               textBox1.Text = mytimepicker.Value.ToString();
          }
         }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Until you have some code and a specific problem, Professor Google will be your best bet. Good luck!!

Comment: Thanks for your response. i am new to C# I created an instance of timepicker "mytime" through a timepicker valuechanged event which was created auto in Xaml. i tried cast mytime.value into a textbox. but it give me nothing.

Comment: Hi Zia - do me a favor and edit your question. Put that code in a code block and let me know what problem you're having with it. Thanks!

Comment: Shannon, Thanks for the help. Due to alot of formalities in WPF i moved back to windows form application. Datetimepicker works for me there..

Answer (score 0):

This shows how to use the Xceed DatePicker:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/wpf-datepicker/

You want to watch the SelectedDatesChanged event.